# Is `ng serve` command suitable for production?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm building a small project using Angular 7.  When you run

```
ng serve
```

and a NodeJS server is spun up to handle requests, does each request block until processing is complete?  We are trying to evaluate how effective using this in production would be as opposed to using a more traditional application server.

Comment: Run `ng serve --prod` on your application. Read the very clear warning displayed on the screen. Evaluation over. Use a real web server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run `build --prod` to generate a "./dist" folder.

Then you have to put that on a web server.

You can use Angular Server Side Rendering (SSR) to run it on a node.js server.

**You should not use `ng serve` for production because it use `webpack-dev-server`** that is build for development only.

[Github link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274)

Comment: Right, my question was geared more towards why I shoudln't use it for production.  Is it because each request to the NodeJS server blocks until processing is complete?

Comment: @Dave updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

`ng serve` runs a webpack development server behind the hood.

a **development server**.

It's made to mimic the production build and see your final application in an esay way.

If you didn't have that command, you would need to run a command like [simplehttpserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simplehttpserver) after rebuilding all of your application on every change.

This is a convenience tool provided by the CLI to ease your development, in no case it's suited for production mode. This is a server without security, without optimization, without performance, without ... Well, without anything that makes a server, a server. By default, it deosn't even make your application accessible outside of your localhost. Not so useful for a production mode ...

So, never, I repeat, **never**, use this command for your production server.

Comment: Oh, and [here is the server used by `ng serve`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#webpack-dev-server)

Answer (score 1):

Run `ng build --prod`
It will generate **minification** code in "dist" folder. you have to upload the file content of this "dist" folder. It will give faster response for loading web pages.

For more details please refer [Angular deployment guide](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Answer (score 0):

When using `ng serve`, you are spawning a backend nodejs environment with a web server to handle requests towards your angular application. That's great for reloading and quick startup when developing. But needing such resources for static pages is unnecessary.

At the end of the day Angular is just a framework telling you its opinion on how to build an SPA. No matter the framework or library you use, you will always end up with an index.xxx, Javascript files and other resource files from vendors or internally. Only these matters to the browser loading the webpage.

Hence, you need to build your app to generate the static files that will be served (i.e. `ng build --prod`). Then you have 2 good options:

1. Choose a web server that will serve the files (i.e. nginx) on a dedicated server (or even container).
2. Place the files behind a CDN provider. Since they are static, they will be cached and served to a browser requesting them based on its location.

I would opt for #2 as opposed to #1 forcing you to keep running resources (CPU, RAM, HDD) for files that will be requested not that often. I say not often because your SPA will be handling all routes within itself in the client's browser (and minimum once a day will request a cache refresh).